# Difference between mysql_errno and mysql_error

Tags: php, mysql

Can anybody explain the difference between mysql_errno and mysql_error?

Answer (score 10):

mysql_errno returns the error code, while mysql_error returns the error text...

Comment: Correct answer yet there is another thing worth mentioning: The last error is reset with most of the mysql_* functions and therefore a programmer should get this error before calling another mysql_* function.

Comment: Hi both displaying the same thing only 
for example :
when i use mysql_errno or mysql_error..

1049: Unknown database 'nonexistentdb'
1146: Table 'kossu.nonexistenttable' doesn't exist


then whats the difference in both these

Comment: @annamalaicse: mysql_error() and mysql_errno() _return_ a value, they do not output it automagically. But e.g. mysql_query() raises a php warning with the same text mysql_error() would return. Your error_reporting and display_errors settings probably cause the output you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the functions of php ?

mysql_errno returns the number of the error,

and mysql_error returns the text of the error.

You can easily find the difference in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 string mysql_error  ([  resource $link_identifier  ] )
```

Returns the error text from the last MySQL function. Errors coming back from the MySQL database backend no longer issue warnings. Instead, use mysql_error()  to retrieve the error text. Note that this function only returns the error text from the most recently executed MySQL function (not including mysql_error() and mysql_errno()), so if you want to use it, make sure you check the value before calling another MySQL function.

`mysql_errno` is the number of the error

Comment: Hi both displaying the same thing only 
for example :
when i use mysql_errno or mysql_error..

1049: Unknown database 'nonexistentdb'
1146: Table 'kossu.nonexistenttable' doesn't exist


then whats the difference in both these

Answer (score 0):

mysql_error — Returns the text of the error message from previous MySQL operation

mysql_errno — Returns the numerical value of the error message from previous MySQL operation

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the topic that MySQL-specific error numbers returned by `mysql_errno()` are not the SQL error numbers you could expect, they differ from SQLSTATE values (returned by `mysql_sqlstate()` or `sqlstate` property inside a `mysqli_sql_exception`). You can find a complete list of error messages and error numbers for your MySQL distribution [here](https://www.oracle.com/search/results/_/N-338?No=0&Nr=106&Nrpp=10&Ntk=SI-ALL5&Ntt=%22Error%20Message%20Reference%22&cat=mysql) (in addition to the `Docs/mysqld_error.txt` file).

Source: [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-sqlstate.html)